# Why isn't the left css property function working in my animate function

Tags: jquery, css

I think I did everything right. But for some reason when I place `left: '20px'` I get an error on the error console

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    Init();

});

//Used for Initializing Events
function Init()
{

    $("p").hover( function()          
    {

        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");

    },
    function()                          
    {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    });

    $("body").fadeIn("slow");
    $("h2").click( function()
    {
        $("h2").animate(
        {
            opacity: .25
            left: '20px'

        }

        );

    });
```

Comment: $('h2').animate({opacity; .25, left: '20px' }); there has to be a comma between more attrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animate's object properties need a comma separating them:

```
{
  opacity: .25,
  left: '20px'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the error?

It might be because there is no comma separating the `opacity` and `left` properties in the `animate` config object.

Also, in JavaScript [opening curly brackets should go on the same line as the function declaration](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html), not on the line below as in other languages

Answer (score 0):

You missed the last `}` for function `Init`, and missed `,` after `opacity: .25`.